# Annotating equations

Tags: equations, annotations

I tried to annotate my equation but the annotation shows up on the opposite side.

```
\begin{equation*}
a+k_nr=a(a^{\varphi(r)})^n \tag{dla n=1,2,\ldots,}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

How do I move it to the right?

Comment: Did you use `leqno` option in your document?

Comment: yeah i did, but when i delete this it makes my the numeration in other equations go to the wrong side

Comment: `\tag` is for custom equation numbers the output goes on the same side as equation numbers.  If you do not show a full document it is hard to guess what has been specified and "go to the wrong side" does not help anyone help you as we do not know which side you expect equation numbers, nor how you have specified them. Please always post a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: also `\tag` is set in text mode, not that you have the wrong `n` and wrong space around `=`

Comment: yeah, gonna fix it, thanks 
while posting I really thought the problem is just connected with that small part , that's why I decided not to attach a complete preamble

Comment: It _always_ helps to provide a complete document. even the code you provide such as `equation*` and `\tag` are not defined by default so you leave us to guess that you have defined them via `amsmath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `flalign` and `\llap` so that it doesn't modify the placement of the main formula:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, leqno]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{flalign}
     & & a+k_nr & =a(a^{\varphi(r)})^n & & \llap{(dla $ n=1,2,\ldots $)}
    \end{flalign}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Possibly not very satisfying for you, but `flalign` can be used:

```
\documentclass[oneside,leqno]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&&a+k_nr=a(a^{\varphi(r)})^n 
&&\text{(dla n=1,2,\ldots,)}
\end{flalign*}

\begin{equation}
c=a+b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it actually does, thank you!

Comment: @MartynaMichalska,  Bernard's answer more useful, because aligning the equations done with it.

Comment: The `n=1,2,\ldots,` particle should be in math mode.

Comment: @Mico, You are absolutely right.